# OR-query on multiple attributes in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table like this:

*Transports*

| id (PK) | createDt | shipperId | carrierId | consigneeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | contact3 | contact2 | contact1 |
| 2 | 24 | contact1 | contact2 | contact3 |
| 3 | 28 | contact3 | contact2 | contact4 |

My access pattern is:

- find all transports where a contact was either shipper, carrier or consignee sorted by createDt. E.g. entering contact1 should return records 1, 2.

How can I do this in DyanomoDB?

I thought about creating a GSI. But then I need to create a separate GSI for each column, which would mean I need to join the query results on the columns myself. Perhaps there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a GSI on the table and split your single record up into multiple ones.
That would make writes slightly more complex, because you write multiple entities, but I'd do something like this:

| PK | SK | type | GSI1PK | GSI1SK | other attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRANSP#1 | TRANSP#1 | transport |  |  | createDt, (shipperId, carrierId, consigneeId)... |
| TRANSP#1 | CONTACT#SHIP | shipper-contact | CONTACT#contact3 | TRANSP#1#SHIP | ... |
| TRANSP#1 | CONTACT#CARR | carrier-contact | CONTACT#contact2 | TRANSP#1#CARR | ... |
| TRANSP#1 | CONTACT#CONS | consignee-contact | CONTACT#contact1 | TRANSP#1#CONS | ... |

- To get all information about a given Transport ID you do a query with `PK=TRANSP#<id>`
- To get just the basic information about a given Transport, you can do a `GetItem` on `PK=TRANSP#<id> and SK=TRANSP<id>` (You could also duplicate the contact infos here if they're fairly static.)
- To get all transports a contact is involved in, you do a `PK=CONTACT#<id> and SK starts with TRANSP` on `GSI1`

If you really need server-side sorting, you might choose a different `GSI1SK`, maybe prefix it with the `dt` value, but I'd probably just do that client side.

Comment: Great answer. I expect some users to have contacts that are in over 50k transports. Is that reasonable to do on the client side?

Comment: Hm, it shouldn't be a problem for any reasonably sized system, but you'd have to always load all contacts, which is going to be expensive. Going for `GSK1SK` in the form of `DATE#<ISO8601-timestamp in UTC>#TRANSP#<id>#SHIP` is also possible, that should allow you to do some `between` queries and things like n oldest/newest entries.